# T-SQL audit table determining when a claim ticket is reopened

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck at how to solve this in t-sql. I keep thinking of doing this via c# or recursive calls of some sort. The idea is given the test case below find how many times a claim ticket was reopened.

```
--assumptions
-- A claim is considered reopened only and only when is opened after
-- its previous state is closed. 
-- an open claim cannot have a closed date


--TEST CASE 1

DECLARE @ClaimHistory TABLE (UserId INT, ClaimdId INT, RefClaimStatus VARCHAR(10), DateOpened DATETIME NOT NULL, DateClosed DATETIME NULL)
DELETE @ClaimHistory
INSERT INTO @ClaimHistory
VALUES
(1,1,'open','1/1/2015',null), 
(1,1,'closed','1/2/2015','1/2/2015'), 
(1,1,'open','1/3/2015',null)

-- First determine the range of dates 
DECLARE @BeginDate DATETIME = '1/1/2014';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '1/4/2015';

SELECT UserId, ClaimdId, RefClaimStatus, DateOpened, DateClosed 
FROM @ClaimHistory
WHERE DateOpened >= @BeginDate   AND  DateOpened <= @EndDate


--Answer the claim was reopened 1 time for user id 1
--TEST Case 2
DELETE @ClaimHistory
INSERT INTO @ClaimHistory
VALUES
(1,1,'open','1/1/2015',null), 
(1,1,'closed','1/2/2015','1/2/2015'), 
(1,1,'open','1/3/2015',null), -- in a sense a claim was transferred to to userid2 . 
(2,1,'open','1/17/2015',null),
(2,1,'closed','1/17/2015','1/19/2015'),
(2,1,'open','1/18/2015',null)

--Answer the claim was 
--1.) reopened 1 time for user 1
--2.) reopened 1 time for user 2


--Test Case 3
DELETE @ClaimHistory
INSERT INTO @ClaimHistory
VALUES
(1,1,'open','1/1/2015',null), 
(1,1,'closed','1/2/2015','1/2/2015'), 
(1,1,'open','1/3/2015',null), 
(1,1,'closed','1/3/2015','1/5/2015'),  -- this means that the last time it was opened was 1/3/2015 and finally closed 1/5/2015
(1,1,'open','1/6/2015',null), -- This guy  is horrible at his job... opens the claim again
(2,1,'open','1/17/2015',null),--boss decides user 1 not good transfers to to userid2 . 
(2,1,'closed','1/17/2015','1/19/2015')

--Answer user id 1 had claimed reopened twice
--user id 2 had his claim was never reopened
```

Answer (score 0):

Can a user open a ticket if it's already opened (by same user or by another user)?

If not, or if such action is also considered as "reopened", then something like this:

```
select UserId, ClaimdId, count(*) - 1 as reopen_count
from @ClaimHistory
where RefClaimStatus = 'open'
group by UserId, ClaimdId
having count(*) > 1
```

UPDATE:

Below script works well for case 1 and case 3, but not for case 2. It seems case 2 is incorrect, the ticket was opened twice by same user, on 1/17, then on 1/18, then closed on 1/19. If the last two rows have correct dates, the script works fine for case 2 as well

```
SELECT ch1.UserId, ch1.ClaimdId, ch1.RefClaimStatus, ch1.DateOpened, ch1.DateClosed 
FROM @ClaimHistory ch1
WHERE ch1.RefClaimStatus = 'Open'
    and ch1.ClaimdId in 
    (SELECT Q.ClaimdId
    FROM
        (SELECT TOP 1 ch2.ClaimdId, ch2.RefClaimStatus
        FROM @ClaimHistory ch2 
        WHERE ch2.ClaimdId = ch1.ClaimdId AND ch1.DateOpened > ISNULL(ch2.DateClosed, ch2.DateOpened)
        ORDER BY ISNULL(ch2.DateClosed, ch2.DateOpened) DESC) Q
    WHERE Q.RefClaimStatus = 'Closed')
```

Comment: it is considered reopened only when it is followed by closed. The examples provided in the the uses cases help on understanding the problem and the correct answers. What I am thinking is that I need to get min opened date. Then use that to determine the next time that user interacted with that claim ticket. If the status is closed then I must continue searching. If I do not see anything else the count must be 0 otherwise if I find a open claim ticket then count becomes 1. Then I recurse over the same logic stated above. The answer is wrong but I really appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: for one specific ticket, can 'closed' state follow 'closed' state in theory? And can 'open' state follow 'open' state with same user id?

E.g.
1,1,closed, 'dd1/mm1/yyyy1', 'dd2/mm2/yyyy2'
1,1,closed, 'dd1/mm1/yyyy1', 'dd3/mm3/yyyy3'

1,1,open, 'dd1/mm1/yyyy1', null
1,1,open, 'dd2/mm2/yyyy2', null

Comment: No if it is closed it cannot be subsequently closed again. Imagine this, you have a work order system if the ticket is closed you cannot close it again. Certainly, you can reopen the ticket but u can never close a closed  ticket.

Comment: it's solvable by TSQL. It's too late now, I'll reply tomorrow if no one submit an answer. The idea is that you need to join each 'closed' state (1) with open state (2) which is TOP 1 ordered by open date with WHERE condition where open date of (2) more than close date of (1)

Comment: Could you check case 2? It seems it's incorrect - see last two inserts.

Comment: hmm the user id is the first column. So the user open , closed, and then open his ticket.

Comment: according to the last 2 rows in case 2, the user opens the ticket on 2016-01-17 and closes it on 2016-01-19.... and at the same time the user opens it on 2016-01-18.  It means the ticket was opened twice by the same user - firstly on 2016-01-17, then on 2016-01-18, then the user closes it on 2016-01-19.

Comment: (2,1,'closed','1/17/2015','1/19/2015'),
(2,1,'open','1/18/2015',null) <- last two rows of case 2.

Comment: yes, it is. Do you think it is correct? Please clarify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120133/discussion-between-hidden-and-anton).